# Is there any alternatives of Monitor Birghtness Reducer with lower RAM usage?

Tags: windows-7, display, brightness

I think question might need little more clarification. Is there any way to recuce screen brightness beyond what windows lets you except Monitor Birghtness Reducer?

I downloaded from here: http://download.cnet.com/Monitor-Brightness-Reducer/3000-2072_4-10690260.html?tag=bc

But it's using too much ram, even the developer accepts it in his readme.txt file
i quote from the read me file, "**

> ... the second side effect is that this program will eat 15 MB of your
>   RAM, just by starting it. This high memory usage is not a bug but it
>   is by design.

**"

Comment: Define "too much ram" and can you include the section about the ram in the readme file in to the text of your question?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but maybe [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) will work for you. It doesn't reduce the brightness actually, but changes color temperature.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain : i added the quotetion from readme file

Comment: @gronostaj : pardon me for not knowing color tempreture. what is it? :) I spent too much on pc and my eyes are getting dry. Even if i decrease brightness to minimum i think my screen still too bright. This is why i need this kind of program

Comment: @TimurAykutYıldırım then I think f.lux will be great for you. It makes your screen look more reddish at night. That's more natural for your eyes when it's dark.

Comment: @gronostaj : Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it tonight and see how it works, right now it's 10 am here

Answer (score 0):

[F.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) should do what you are requesting with a minimum of fuss.